# Unable to disable specific compiler warning (4100)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to disable the 4100 for a particular project; but adding it to the disabled warnings list (a.k.a., adding a wd flag) has no effect. I have a couple other warnings disabled in the same fashion successfully for the same project; further, I can disable the warning by adding the appropriate #pragma warning to the source.

Is there some particular aspect of my project or the 4100 warning that prevents it from being disabled in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all of the includes that your source file pulls in.  One of them likely explicitly enables the warning or resets warnings to their default state.  I've seen this with either MFC or ATL headers that come with VC++.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it - one of the headers is disabling the warning but re-enabling it with a "default" call specifier rather than using a push/pop pair.